# Why does mail php function takes app. 5-7 seconds to execute?

Tags: php, email

It takes about 5 to 7 seconds to execute sending the email. On my local server MAMP it takes just half a second. On a website it takes 5 to 7 seconds(Whereas it is expected to take half a second).I would really appreciate your help.

```
<?php
$mail_to = 'rafalmietkiewicz@gmail.com'; // specify your email here

// Assigning data from $_POST array to variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail_from = $_POST['email'];


// Construct subject of the email
$subject = 'Nowa osoba zapisała się na newsletter Przeglądu Psychologicznego ' . $name;

// Construct email body
$body_message = 'Imię i nazwisko: ' . $name . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Adres e-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";


// Construct headers of the message
$headers = 'From: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_sent == true){ ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Dziękujemy!');
    window.location = '../index.php';
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Adres e-mail nie został wysłany. Proszę spróbować raz jeszcze.');
    window.location = '../index.php';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: As it works fast on your localhost, I would assume the code is not dodgy So it would point to your mailserver on the web server. Or too much traffic on the local network, others using the same services on shared hosting, some bottleneck with the SMPT service, or all manner of potential things. Have a looksie at the maillog

Comment: I've tested it again and it performs quickly on MAMP locally, but... the emails are not actually sent... Now I'm stupid... :(

I host on digitalocean on a private server with no big traffic...

Comment: How did you measure the time it takes to execute? Is that the time needed to execute the code or until your mail arrives?

Comment: What did you find in the logs? You have a private server so should be simple to access them.

Comment: It takes that long from clicking on submit to showing the message "Thank you". I've founded some clue that it may have something to do with multiple domain configuration, but it makes me even more lost:

They say one should add:

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Standard stuff goes here

    <Directory /dir/to/your/web/root>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fuser@domain2.com"
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

what makes me even more lost on how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, the solution was to add to /etc/hosts the following line:

127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain abstynencja

(previous didn't have localhost.localdomain input)

It works like a charm now, but can anyone tell me, what's the difference?